# Default 'Complete linked work items after merging' to unchecked

Tags: azure-devops

A new feature of PR completion appeared in VSTS where PRs marked complete by default also mark linked work items as complete, unless unchecked.

Is it possible to default this to unchecked in the case where this checkbox may be missed?

[image: Complete PR dialog]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of August 28th, 2017, you're able to change the default behavior of this checkbox.

While it does default to "checked", you're now able to change a setting that allows it to remember your last-used options when completing pull requests.

You're able to do this by going to `Admin Settings > Version Control > Select Repo`. Under Repo Options, check "Remember user preferences for completing owrk items with pull requests." to have it save your preferred default behavior.

Source: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/105380/view.html

Comment: RE: While it does default to "checked". The doco says:

_If the new setting is disabled, then the Complete linked work items after merging option will default to **disabled** for all PRs in the repository. _ [Doco here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/devops/release-notes/2017/aug-28-team-services#complete-work-items-settings)

Comment: Linked source is a dead link.

Comment: Linked source is dead and the solution is not working. The `Admin Settings > Version Control > Select Repo` doesn't exist anymore. I wonder if there is still a way to change the default behavior where the checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 4):

No way to change the default behavior. There is a feedback that you can follow and vote: ['Complete linked work items after merging' is dangerous as a default option](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/83849/complete-linked-work-items-after-merging-is-danger.html)