# n Azure Devops pull requests.Complete associated work items after merging disable

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-deployment, azure-devops-server-2019

In Azure Devops I have a git repository with a develop branch. We create multiple feature branches from this branch and merge code into develop via pull requests. Once we complete the pull requests the work items got completed. its all closed from various states.

I want to prevent this from happening. I'd like to keep these feature branches. How can I do that?

Comment: Check this anwser! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45272396/default-complete-linked-work-items-after-merging-to-unchecked

Answer (score 10):

> Once we complete the pull requests the work items got completed. its all closed from various states.

The root cause of this issue is `Complete associated work items after merging` option. When you complete the Pull Request and this option is enabled, the related work items will close.

To solve this issue, you could disable this option.

[image]

You can also set it to be disabled by default.

You could navigate to `Project Settings -> Repositories -> Select target Repo -> Options` and disable `Remember user preferences for completing work items with pull requests` option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kevin, this is solving my query in some extend, I need to permanent disable option "Complete linked work items after merging" .

Comment: Hi @dilipbhapkar. I understand your requirement. But it doesn't support permanently disabling it now. Here is  a suggestion ticket about this feature: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/1046560/allow-disable-option-complete-linked-work-items-af.html You could vote and add comment in it.  I also hope that azure devops can achieve this function in the future.

Comment: Hello! I'm trying to find this option, but I can't find it anywhere in DevOps settings. Does this option no longer exist?

Comment: The option name has changed. Current name:** Work item transition preferences**

Answer (score 0):

latest screenshot of the setting being talked about

[image]